How can i upload image to firebase storage from compose multiplatform ImageBitmap?
    @OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
    override fun uploadImage(
        path: String,
        data: ImageBitmap,
        onSuccess: (String) -> Unit,
        onFailure: (String) -> Unit
    ) {
        val ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(path)
        data.toNSData()?.let {
            ref.putData(it, null) { _, nsError ->
                if(nsError == null) {
                    ref.downloadURLWithCompletion { nsUrl, nsError1 ->
                        if (nsError1 == null){
                            nsUrl?.absoluteString?.let(onSuccess)?: onFailure("empty String")
                        } else {
                            onFailure(nsError1.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    onFailure(nsError.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        } ?: run {
            onFailure("Couldn't convert to byteArray")
        }
    }

@OptIn(BetaInteropApi::class)
fun ImageBitmap.toNSData() : NSData? {
    return this.asSkiaBitmap().readPixels()?.toNSData()
}

@BetaInteropApi
@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
fun ByteArray.toNSData(): NSData = memScoped {
    NSData.create(bytes = allocArrayOf(this@toNSData), length = this@toNSData.size.toULong())
}

here i am getting ImageBitmap and i want to upload this image on given path
i don't know what i am doing wrong as i am new to IOS development with kmp

I got solution for this problem
here it is
private fun UIImage.toNSData(): NSData? {
    return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(this, 0.8)
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
fun ImageBitmap.toUIImage(): UIImage? {
    val width = this.width
    val height = this.height
    val buffer = IntArray(width * height)

    this.readPixels(buffer)

    val colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    val context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
        data = buffer.refTo(0),
        width = width.toULong(),
        height = height.toULong(),
        bitsPerComponent = 8u,
        bytesPerRow = (4 * width).toULong(),
        space = colorSpace,
        bitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast.value
    )

    val cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
    return cgImage?.let { UIImage.imageWithCGImage(it) }
}

